# React - Calling a specific function when 'Enter' key is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard

Didn't succeed in using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520587/react-detect-enter-key-press-in-change-event) thread to help. 
I have button div with an `onClick` that invokes a `handleSendMessage`.

I want this `handleSendMessage` to be invoked whenever a user presses the 'Enter' key
while on the page. 
How can I do that?

Component looks like this :

```
    const ChatScreen = () => {
      const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      let chatsFromState = useSelector(state => state.chatsState.chats);

      const socket = io("localhost:4000");

      socket.on("RECEIVE_MESSAGE", msgReceived => {
        console.log("msgReceived ", msgReceived);
      });

      const handleChange = e => setMessage(e.target.value);

      const handleSendMessage = async () => {
        socket.emit("SEND_MESSAGE", message);
        await dispatch(sendMessage(message));
        setMessage("");
      };

      return (
        <div className="chatScreen">
          <div className="">HI</div>
          <input
            value={message}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Your message here..."
          />
          <div className="sendBtn" onClick={handleSendMessage}>
            Send
          </div>
          <div className="messagesContainer">
            {chatsFromState.map((chat, i) => (
              <div className="messageBox" key={i}>
                message : {chat.message}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default ChatScreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `onKeyPress` keyboard event to your input element you could capture the key event and then check for the `key` Enter.

The event happens in the `input` since this is where the user has focus, if the user clicked anywhere else on the page, the focus would be lost and this won't work anymore. The trick here is thinking where the focus might be and listen to that.

Here is a very retrieved example, just be sure to focus on the input and hit Enter, a message will be logged:

```js
const ChatScreen = () => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('setMessage');
    }
  }

  return (<input type="text" onKeyPress={handleChange} />);
}

const root = document.getElementById('container')
 
ReactDOM.render(<ChatScreen />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```